# CSS Shadow on Clipped or Masked Div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's full size when hovered over but clipped on all edges when the mouse goes away. It shows a drop shadow when the div is fully visible, as below:

[image]

---

#### Instead of the above, I'd like the *reverse* shadow behavior:  Show a drop shadow *when the div is clipped* and hide the shadow when the div is fully visible.

Perhaps clipping is not the right mechanic and I need a mask or another div that can cast the shadow instead?

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: mediumslateblue;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px);
  clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px);
}

.card:hover {
  -webkit-clip-path: none;
  clip-path: none;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
  <div class="card">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is using `filter: drop-shadow();` while wrapping your `.card` in a container.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
.card--wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card--wrapper:not(:hover) {
  /* We want shadow on clipped box instead, now whole box */
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}

.card {
  width: inherit;
  height: 200px;
  background: mediumslateblue;
  pointer-events: auto;
  
  /* Clip div when not hovered */
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px);
  clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px);
}

.card:hover {
  /* Show full div on hover */
  -webkit-clip-path: none;
  clip-path: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="card--wrapper">
    <div class="card">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, very helpful. One thing left -- is there a way to *remove* the shadow when the div is full size (i.e.: on hover in the example)?

I tried adding `card--wrapper:hover { filter:none }`, but the `card--wrapper` dimensions don't match the clipped `card`, which makes the hover effect buggy.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is more or less what I tried, but the dimensions don't match so the hover effect happens at the wrong time. See end of gif: https://imgur.com/a/ZPr8c

Comment: @laverick I see the issue. I have updated my answer with `pointer-event`s. If this doesn't work, then my solution won't be adequate for your needs, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JaKhris Thanks - that almost does it, actually. It now works on all sides except when I hover off on the right -- looks like the wrapper is wider than the card. If I set the wrapper width to match the card width `card--wrapper { width: 400px }` it seems to work exactly as expected.

Comment: @laverick Ah yes, good catch. As I'm on mobile, I couldn't test properly. Good to hear you figured that out!

Comment: Slight bug with putting it in the `.card--wrapper:not(:hover)` style, I think it needs to go into a plain `.card--wrapper` style.

Comment: I am all over the place today, sorry. I edited my answer, which should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clipping, put the div inside a container with these properties:

```
.container {
  width: 360px;                      /* width when clipped */
  height: 160px;                     /* height when clipped */
  overflow: hidden;                  /* don't grow to match contents */
  transform: translate(20px, 20px);  /* maintain centering */
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

Set the div to its full width and height, but translate it to simulate clipping:

```
.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(-20px, -20px);
}
```

When hovering the div and its container, remove their translations:

```
.container:hover, .card:hover {
  transform: none;
}
```

When hovering the container, set its width to the div's width, the height to auto, and remove the box-shadow:

```
.container:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.card {
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(-20px, -20px);
  font: 20px arial;
}

.container {
  width: 360px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(20px, 20px);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.container:hover, .card:hover {
  transform: none;
}

.container:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, super helpful! This is very close, but it acts a little buggy when the mouseover happens on the right side. Any idea how to fix that?

https://imgur.com/a/0y0aB

Comment: See my update.  Funny how the issue happened only on the right.  I would expect it to happen on the bottom as well.